# How to disable options as COPY in generated PDF file?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

When I generate a PDF with *JasperReports 6.9.0* I don't want the user to be able to copy text from it.

I've added the encryption library bcprov-jdk14-139.jar, and restarted the server. Then I've wrote the three properties to my .jxrml file:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.encrypted" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.128.bit.key" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.owner.password" value="12345"/>
```

and the permissions property:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed" value="SCREENREADERS"/>
```

I've compiled and restarted the server, then I've tried it but it doesn't work, both Java code and .jrxml code, but I can copy/paste text from the PDF, can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of JasperReports library are you using?

Comment: JasperReports Library version 6.9.0

Comment: WOW, recently news!!! It works if I open the pdf with Acrobat Reader, but don't work with Firefox Pdf plugin, why?????

Comment: I suppose that you can implement your own application for viewing pdf file that totally will ignore all permissions. Looks like the authors of plugin did the same :)